# figuring out 3rd of a note

Tags: chords, intervals

I am having a hard time just to figure out 3rd of a given note, in fact in backward.

For example, G's 3rd in backward is E and F's is D.

It does not come out as naturally as I wish it to.

Is there a certain exercise on this problem other than just tons of scale exercise?

Comment: "It does not come out as naturally as I wish it to": why?  What's your expectation?  From my perspective, and I daresay that of other users of this site, it is elementary that D is a third below F, and E a third below G, and I can't remember thinking anything inconsistent with this when I was a beginner, so it's not clear to me how to formulate an answer that you would find useful.  "Is there a certain exercise on this problem other than just tons of scale exercise?: Are you asking about theory or about playing an instrument?  Which instrument?

Comment: I'm with @phoog on this. On its face, your question seems to be about how to do a rote memorization exercise: C-A, D-B, E-C, F-D, G-E, A-F, B-G. Is there something beyond that that you have as a goal? Answers to the questions phoog poses would be very helpful.

Comment: Is going a sixth up easier?

Comment: Do you need this knowledge for singing or guitarplaying? What instrument are you playing? Are you able to read sheet music? Mind there are different qualities of thireds: minor thirds and major thirds, e.g.

Comment: For what concrete situation do you need this? Why do you need to spell out the letter names? Or do you need to write music or play an instrument? For writing staff notation, you don't need to think of the letter names, a third is always at a certain distance. For playing instruments you don't need letter names either, because what you want to locate is how to play the note on your instrument, and that's largely a spatial task, not textual. Maybe for reading chord symbols, it might be good to quickly know when a chord symbol specifies a certain inversion, and for that you'd need the letters.

Answer (score 1):

Reciting a series backwards can be tricky. Just think of the alphabet. You probably cannot recite it backwards anywhere near as easily as forward! Keep that in mind and realize you need to spend some time reciting pitch letter series backwards before it will become easy.

I think there are three basic pitch letter series to know:

- stepwise: `A B C D E F G A, A G F E D C B A`
- by thirds `A C E G B D F A, A F D B G E C A`
- by fifths `A E B F C G D A, A D G C F B E A`

Probably the two most practical times to work on those series are during practice drill of scales and arpeggios, and while doing harmonic analysis of chords where you identify pitch letters.

Comment: 1st is dead easy! 3rd is the circle of 5ths. But the 2nd version is the worst! Unless you consider the notes used in each chord of its 11th. Which I doubt OP will cope with.

Comment: My example of reciting by thirds is not meant to be literally starting with `A` as a root. I don't mean to memorize an `A` thirteenth chord. You could start with any letter. The point is to be able to recite by thirds ascending and descending, which is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The question's not as clear as it could be, but guessing what it's asking -

Take any note, call that the major chord. Instead of going down a third, learn what the **relative minor** chord in relation to that will be. That's easily found by counting up to ^6.

As in:

- G(maj) -> E(min)
- C(maj) -> A(min)
- F(maj) -> D(min)

Of course, sharps or flats will come into the equation, depending on the key signature, as in A(maj)>F♯(min).

Most people will know the common chord sequence 1-6-4-5, and the 6 part is the one you call 'three down'. And, yes, usage of these chord sequences will embed the relationships between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you need this knowledge for a music test:

In this case the easiest way is to go back 2 letters in the alphabet:

a b c d e f g a b c d e f g
you need to imagine the scale-names like a ladder, you have to write it down 10 times and then you also must write 2 scales:

A B C D E F G A B C D E F G A B  ....

Then you write another scale above or below the one you have  on your sheet, beginning with 2 letters before or later:

C D E F G A B C D E F G A B C D E F ....

A B C D E F G A B C D E F G A B C D ....

C D E F G A B C D E F G A B C D E F ....

you have to make a "photocopy" in your mind (vizualisation!)
this is a very important trick of learning.

if you play piano or a keyboard then you must draw the keys and names on a sheet of paper (you can do this every time before you start playing an instrument or singing) The third is always two white keys from the given tone, so you have to skip one white key)

If your goal is to recognize a third in a notated sheet (staff) the way is also very easy: if a note is on a line, its third (up or down) is on the next line, the same rule is when the note is in a space between 2 lines:
the thirds are in the next space.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staff_(music)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(music)

So you need to know and understand the terms **STAFF and INTERVAL**

Comment: I used to do similar with students - a 'Blue Peter' approach (UK tv prog.) using two concentric circles, one bigger than the other, like clock faces. Easier to rotate and read off.